bruno script - how to avoid calling getEnvVar("key") if that key does not exist?
how to avoid calling bru.getEnvVar("key") if that key does not exist  ?
bru.getEnvVar("key") throw an exception if that key does not exist. is there a way to validate that key if it is defined as environment variable or not.
